# Counting number of instances of a condition per row R

Tags: r, rows, frequency

I have a large file with the first column being IDs, and the remaining 1304 columns being genotypes like below.

```
rsID    sample1    sample2    sample3...sample1304
abcd    aa         bb         nc        nc
efgh    nc         nc         nc        nc 
ijkl    aa         ab         aa        nc
```

I would like to count the number of "nc" values per row and output the result of that to another column so that I get the following:

```
rsID    sample1    sample2    sample3...sample1304    no_calls
abcd    aa         bb         nc        nc            2
efgh    nc         nc         nc        nc            4
ijkl    aa         ab         aa        nc            1
```

The table function counts frequencies per column, not row and if I transpose the data to use in the table function, I would need the file to look like this:

```
abcd         aa[sample1]
abcd         bb[sample2]
abcd         nc[sample3] ...
abcd         nc[sample1304]
efgh         nc[sample1]
efgh         nc[sample2]
efgh         nc[sample3] ...
efgh         nc[sample1304]
```

With this format, I would get the following which is what I want:

```
ID    nc   aa   ab   bb
abcd  2    1    0    1
efgh  4    0    0    0
```

Does anybody have any idea of an simple way to get frequencies by row? I am trying this right now, but it is taking quite some time to run:

```
rsids$Number_of_no_calls <- apply(rsids, 1, function(x) sum(x=="NC"))
```

Comment: R is case sensitive. The data shows "nc" but the apply "NC"...¿?

Comment: `rowSums` is probably the right function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`.

```
df$no_calls <- rowSums(df == "nc")
df
#  rsID sample1 sample2 sample3 sample1304 no_calls
#1 abcd      aa      bb      nc         nc        2
#2 efgh      nc      nc      nc         nc        4
#3 ijkl      aa      ab      aa         nc        1
```

Or, as pointed out by MrFlick, to exclude the first column from the row sums, you can slightly modify the approach to

```
df$no_calls <- rowSums(df[-1] == "nc")
```

---

Regarding the row names: They are not counted in `rowSums` and you can make a simple test to demonstrate it:

```
rownames(df)[1] <- "nc"  # name first row "nc"
rowSums(df == "nc")      # compute the row sums
#nc  2  3             
# 2  4  1        # still the same in first row
```

Comment: Maybe `df$no_calls <- rowSums(df[,-1] == "nc")` to ignore any "nc" values in the first column.

Comment: @MrFlick, good point if there can be any in that column

Comment: @doc Will the original code you posted count "nc" values in the first column if the first column is read in as row names?

Comment: @nchimato, no it won't.