# how to go through all my variables and detect a characteristic

Tags: r

I want to go through all variables of my dataset and detect all "yes" then put their number per individual in a new variable `"n_yes"`

```
mydata<-data.frame(
  
  aa=c("yes","no",NA,"yes",NA),
  bb=c("no","yes",NA,"unknown",NA),
  klm=c("no","no",NA,"yes",NA),
  ncv=c("no","no",NA,"no",NA),
  d3d=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    )
```

I want to get such a table below:

```
    aa      bb  klm  ncv d3d n_yes
1  yes      no   no   no  NA     1
2   no     yes   no   no  NA     1
3 <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA     0
4  yes unknown  yes   no  NA     2
5 <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA     0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting number of instances of a condition per row R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618583/counting-number-of-instances-of-a-condition-per-row-r)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner:

```
rowSums(mydata == "yes", na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 0 2 0
```

Or, if you want to create a new column with these results,

```
mydata$n_yes <- rowSums(mydata == "yes", na.rm = TRUE)
```